# Disable jsonld metadata for @Embedded objects

Tags: doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I've been looking for an answer to this (seemingly simple) problem but I found none so far.

I have a `VatAmount` designed like so :

```php
/**
 * ValueObject defining the amount both with and without VAT.
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 * @property int $total
 * @property int|null $withoutVat
 * @Assert\EnableAutoMapping()
 */
class VatAmount
{
    /**
     * TTC
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(50)
     */
    protected $total = 0;

    /**
     * HT
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $withoutVat;

    ...
```

Then I use it in multiple Entities :

```php
class Bill
{
    /**
     * @Embedded(class=VatAmount::class)
     */
    private $amount;

    ...
}
```

Finally, I add it to my serialization groups :

```yaml
App\Entity\Billing\Bill:
  attributes:
    amount:
      groups: ["bill:read", "order:detail"]
   ...

App\Entity\Embeddable\VatAmount:
  attributes:
    total:
      groups: ["amount:read", "amount:write"]
    withoutVat:
      groups: ["amount:read", "amount:write"]
```

It means that `VatAmount` no only isn't an `ApiResource`, it's not even a real Entity and it has no ID of its own.

Before I upgraded from api-platform 2.5.7 to 2.6.3, jsonld metadata (@id, @context, @type) was present on OpenApi doc but not when I actually fetched the resource. I simply removed the OpenApi fields and all was fine.

But now that I upgraded, whenever I fetch the resource, I get that :

```php
  "amount" => array:4 [
    "@type" => "VatAmount"
    "@id" => "_:46842"
    "total" => 1000
    "withoutVat" => 800
  ]
```

I'm not even really sure what `_:46842` refers to and I want it gone.

So my question is: is there any way to disable these fields for a specific class or nested resource ?

I tried :

- playing with `ApiProperty(jsonldContext={})`
- using `ApiResource(hydraContext={})`

Both seem like dead ends and I can't find any doc on what fields are accepted in these contexts.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where this comes from. Strangely enough, all the code responsible for this feature seems to have been around for a long time so I'm not sure what has changed with the latest updates to make it work.

Whenever an anonymous embedded object is serialized, `ObjectNormalizer::normalize()` is called. This class is injected with an `AnonymousContextBuilderInterface` (by default, `ContextBuilder`) which it will pass down to `JsonLdContextTrait` to build the context. The `ContextBuilder::getAnonymousResourceContext()` method will return an array where `@id` is PHP's internal ID :

```php
'@id' => $context['iri'] ?? '_:'.(\function_exists('spl_object_id') ? spl_object_id($object) : spl_object_hash($object)),
```

I haven't found any way to configure this behaviour.

With that in mind, I created a `VoidContextBuilder` which returns an empty array on `getAnonymousResourceContext()` and injected it in place of `ContextBuilder` with a compiler pass :

```php
$def = $container->getDefinition('api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.object');
$def->setArgument('$anonymousContextBuilder', new Reference('App\Util\VoidContextBuilder'));
```

This works but it doesn't seem to fix OpenApi view so I kept the code I had before :

```php
if (substr($name, 0, 9) === 'VatAmount') {
 unset($schema['properties']['@context']);
 unset($schema['properties']['@id']);
 unset($schema['properties']['@type']);
}
```

Please tell me if there is a better, safer way to get rid of anonymous resources' jsonld context.

Comment: Got the same issue and i have made a decorator on AnonymousContextBuilderInterface, same result but cleaner than compiler pass i think